# React material ui table can't get element from row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use a table from the material ui library for react :
http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table

I display it, it works very well, I m trying to get the object associated with the row I selected, but I don't find the way to do that, I saw the property `children` or `onRowSelection` but I can't get my object here is my code.
How can I get the entire object of my selected line ?

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'

import Table from 'material-ui/lib/table/table';
import TableHeaderColumn from 'material-ui/lib/table/table-header-column';
import TableRow from 'material-ui/lib/table/table-row';
import TableHeader from 'material-ui/lib/table/table-header';
import TableRowColumn from 'material-ui/lib/table/table-row-column';
import TableBody from 'material-ui/lib/table/table-body';


export default class MagicTableReact extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data : [{id:0,name:"joe"},{id:1,name:"john"},{id:2,name:"Brad"},{id:3,name:"Jack"},{id:4,name:"Andrew"}],
            fixedHeader: true,
            fixedFooter: true,
            stripedRows: false,
            showRowHover: true,
            selectable: true,
            multiSelectable: false,
            enableSelectAll: false,
            deselectOnClickaway: true,
            height: '300px',
        };
    };


    _onRowSelection(e){
        console.log(e)

    }


    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <h1>MagicTableReact</h1>
                    <Table
                        height={this.state.height}
                        fixedHeader={this.state.fixedHeader}
                        fixedFooter={this.state.fixedFooter}
                        selectable={this.state.selectable}
                        multiSelectable={this.state.multiSelectable}
                        >
                        <TableHeader>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                                <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHeader>
                        <TableBody
                        >
                            {this.state.data.map((user, i) =>
                                <TableRow key={i}
                                    onRowSelection={this._onRowSelection.bind(this)}>
                                    <TableRowColumn>{user.id}</TableRowColumn>
                                    <TableRowColumn>{user.name}</TableRowColumn>
                                </TableRow>
                            )}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

MagicTableReact.propTypes = {

};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> UPDATE: With material-ui 0.15.4, the parameters passed to the onRowSelection handler have been changed. See answer from @Jonathn for correct usage going forward.

`onRowSelection` is a property of `<Table>` not `<TableRow>`. Also, it doesn't call the handler with an event when called (`e`), rather, it will call it with the key. You can then use that to find the row. Like so:

```
_onRowSelection(key) {
  console.log(key, this.state.data[key])
},

getInitialState() {
  return {
    data : [{id:0,name:"joe"},{id:1,name:"john"},{id:2,name:"Brad"},{id:3,name:"Jack"},{id:4,name:"Andrew"}],
    fixedHeader: true,
    fixedFooter: true,
    stripedRows: false,
    showRowHover: true,
    selectable: true,
    multiSelectable: false,
    enableSelectAll: false,
    deselectOnClickaway: true,
    height: '300px',
  };
},

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <h1>MagicTableReact</h1>
        <Table
          height={this.state.height}
          fixedHeader={this.state.fixedHeader}
          fixedFooter={this.state.fixedFooter}
          selectable={this.state.selectable}
          multiSelectable={this.state.multiSelectable}
          onRowSelection={this._onRowSelection}
        >
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody
          >
            {this.state.data.map((user, i) =>
              <TableRow key={i} value={user}>
                <TableRowColumn>{user.id}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{user.name}</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer is logical :)

Comment: For me,  when i set the key to an _id of an item, it gets passed to the onRowSelection handler as the row index, not the key.

Comment: This could be a change. It never made sense before. Although the parameter 'key' is actually an interesting index.

Answer (score 6):

> Using [Material-UI 0.15.4]

`onRowSelection` only returns `none`, `all` or an array containing the row number of the row(s) selected.

Using `onCellClick`, also at `<Table>` level, returns `rowNumber`, `columnNumber` and the `event`. This event contains the table cell under `target` and you can reference a `data-` tag, etc. from there.

Example:

```
function handleCellClick (rowNumber, columnNumber, evt) {
  console.log("activityId", evt.target.dataset.myRowIdentifier);
}

function createTableRow (content) {
  let activityId = content.shift();
  return (
    <TableRow key={activityId}>
      {content.map((columnContent, i) => {
        return (
          <TableRowColumn key={i} data-my-row-identifier={activityId} >{columnContent}</TableRowColumn>
        );
      })}
    </TableRow>
  );
}

return (
  <div>
    <Table onCellClick={handleCellClick}>
      <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>
      {createHeaderRow(tableHeader)}
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
      {filteredTable.map(createTableRow)}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </div>
);
```

My first answer on StackOverflow ... hope it helps :-)

Comment: I'm unable to get this solution to work. I've tried accessing the data-attribute in both `target` and in `currentTarget` but it is always undefined.

Comment: See [this issue here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/5711) from Material UI. It explains why this answer no longer works in Material-UI v0.16. Sounds like they are trying to address it though.

Comment: I just tried it and it work with 0.20.0 so they may have fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Table onCellClick={(row, col, event) => console.log(event.target.innerHTML)}>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your initial data array and reference the index based on the row number to access your selected rows and the object that's associated with it. This is a basic example and obviously depending on what you want to do with the data you may need to add more logic.

```
_onRowSelection(rows) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.state.data[rows[i]])
    }
},

getInitialState() {
  return {
    data : [{id:0,name:"joe"},{id:1,name:"john"},{id:2,name:"Brad"},{id:3,name:"Jack"},{id:4,name:"Andrew"}]
  };
},

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <h1>MagicTableReact</h1>
        <Table onRowSelection={(rows) => this._onRowSelection(rows)}>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody
          >
            {this.state.data.map((user, i) =>
              <TableRow key={i} value={user}>
                <TableRowColumn>{user.id}</TableRowColumn>
                <TableRowColumn>{user.name}</TableRowColumn>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```