# Getting data from TableRow component in Material UI

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I'm using a Table component in the newest version of Material UI, and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be acquiring data from a Table's row when it's selected.

The documentation mentions a prop for the Table component called `onRowSelection`, but it only gives you a RowNumber for the row that was selected, nothing else.

How are you supposed to make any use of this at all?  I don't understand how you're meant to grab say...the key prop that's set to the `TableRow` using nothing but the RowNumber prop of that same `TableRow`.

Code below shows how I'm rendering the table itself, and assigning the key:

```
handleSelect(id) {
  console.log(id);
  this.props.dispatch({ type: 'SET_SELECTED_USER', user: id });
}

renderUsers() {
  if (this.props.users && this.props.currentUser) {
    const currUser = this.props.currentUser.username;
    const userList = this.props.users.map((user) => {
      if (currUser !== user.username) {
        return (
          <TableRow key={user._id}>
            <TableRowColumn>{user.username}</TableRowColumn>
            <TableRowColumn>{user.roles[0]}</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
        );
      }
    });
    return userList;
  }
}
```

I just don't understand how the RowNumber of the row being selected is supposed to help me whatsoever, when I need to access they key of the row instead.

Any assistance would be really appreciated!  Thanks!

Docs for Table:  http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table

Comment: Is the same question answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656447/react-material-ui-table-cant-get-element-from-row

Comment: In a way, I guess...but my problem seems to be that, contrary to how that question is replied, the `key` prop isn't what's being used to identify the row being selected when using `onRowSelection`.  Instead, some abritrary `rowNumber` property is automatically generated by `Table` and is used, which is not helpful at all, when I actually need it to be using the `key` prop as suggested by that question/answer.

Comment: You can populate the key value with whatever you want. Look at the row creation .map in the example in that linked question/answer. You can even link to the full object. Does that help?

Comment: I don't know.  The problem isn't being able to stick whatever values I want in the key/value props for the rows as they're created.  The problem is that when I go to trigger the selection of said rows, I don't understand how I'm supposed to access those props, when you're only able to pass one parameter (I guess?) into the function that gets called when triggering `onRowSelection`.  Unless I'm wrong, and my code for `handleSelect` above could be something like `function handleSelect(row, key) ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the row number as an index in your users array (this.props.users):

```
handleSelect(userIndex) {
  const currUser = this.props.currentUser.username;
  const users = this.props.users.filter(user => user.username !== currUser)
  this.props.dispatch({ type: 'SET_SELECTED_USER', user: users[userIndex].id });
}
```

Comment: I will definitely give this a shot tonight and report back with results!

Comment: Upon testing this code this evening, this works perfectly.   Thank you very much, answer has been accepted for sure!  Thanks again!